# How to write XML tags by using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, xml

I tried to write xml tags by using BufferWriterBut,when i am trying to open a file it is displaying like empty page.The code is like below

```
bw.write("<?xml version=" + "\"1.0\"" + " " + "encoding=" + "\"UTF-8\""
                + "?>");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("<con:soapui-project activeEnvironment=" + "\"Default\"" + " "
                + " name=" + "\"REST Project 1\"" + " " + "soapui-version="
                + "\"4.6.4\"" + " " + "xmlns:con="
                + "\"http://eviware.com/soapui/config\"" + ">");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("<con:settings/>");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("<con:interface xsi:type=" + "\"con:RestService\"" + " "
                + "wadlVersion=" + "\"http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02\"" + " "
                + "name=" + "\"" + baseUrl1 + "\"" + "" + " " + "type="
                + "\"rest\"" + " " + "xmlns:xsi="
                + "\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" + ">");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("<con:settings/>");
```

Can i write the xml tags like above or is there any way to write xml tags

Comment: Why not use JAXB or any reasonable means to manipulate with XML?

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample exmaple to write an xml tags

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? You could use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) and search for `marshalling`.

For starters you could refer to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/).

Answer (score 1):

A `BufferWriter`, as the name implies, has a buffer and it will only flush the buffer to the file when one of three conditions are met:

1. The buffer is full
2. You flush the buffer manually calling `flush()`
3. The writer is closed

None of them apply in your case, so the file stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

If JAXB is to difficult for you, try the DOM Parser. Its pretty simple.

[DOM Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Documentbuilder Class instead. It has Element interface which can be used to write xml tags more efficiently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).